# App crashing on setText in InfoWindow

Tags: android, android-layout, infowindow, settext

I have this problem with my InfoWindow in my Android app. When I run this code:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lkonty, null);

    TextView txtName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtName.setText(marker.getTitle());
    return view;
```

The app crashes while running the setText method. I found a solution by adding this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.lkonty);
```

The app is no longer crashing but now the InfoWindow fills the whole screen and I don't know how to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
 .inflate(R.layout.lkonty,parent,false);


TextView txtName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

txtName.setText(marker.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

App crashes because your textview `txtName` is null.
You must find your `txtName` by `view` you inflated.
It will like this:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lkonty, null);

    TextView txtName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtName.setText(marker.getTitle());
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to use you **view** while binding your textview.

```
 TextView txtName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
```

you have to use **view** while use of inflater.